# How to use Struct with Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, struct

In my iOS project I use Firestore as my database. In order to retrieve data from the database i used the following code:

```
 let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Restaurant_Aggregated_List_3").document("Test")
      
    docRef.getDocument { document, error in
    
        guard error == nil, let document = document, document.exists, let restaurants = document.get("Restaurants")  as? [RestaurantsAPIResponse] else { return }
        completion(restaurants)
    }
}
```

And the output that I get looks like the following:

```
["XYZ789": ["latitude": 0.222, "longitude": 0.333, "uid": XYZ789, "name": Test2, "address_1": Full Address 2, "full_address": Full Address 2, Postcode 5678, City 2], "ABC123": ["uid": ABC123, "address_1": Full Address 1, "full_address": Full Address 1, Postcode 1234, City 1, "name": Test1, "longitude": 4.444, "latitude": 1.111]]
```

Although, I can now read the data from the database, I understood the best practice is to use a Struct to replace [String:[String:Any]] with a Struct (in this case "RestaurantsAPIResponse"). See below code example:

```
struct RestaurantsAPIResponse{
let Country: String
let CountryCode: String
let Restaurants: [String: Restaurants]}

struct Restaurants {
let uid: String
let name: String
let address_1: String
let latitude: Double
let longitude: Double

init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
    self.address_1 = dictionary["address_1"] as? String ?? ""
    self.latitude = dictionary["latitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0
    self.longitude = dictionary["longitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0
}}
```

Here is the method I used:

```
  static func fetchRestaurantAggregatedList(completion: @escaping([RestaurantsAPIResponse]) -> Void) {
    
    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Restaurant_Aggregated_List_3").document("Test")
    
    docRef.getDocument { document, error in
    
        guard error == nil, let document = document, document.exists, let restaurants = document.get("Restaurants")  as? [RestaurantsAPIResponse] else { return }
        completion(restaurants)
    }
}

   func fetchRestaurants() {
    RestaurantService.fetchRestaurantAggregatedList { fetchedRestaurantList in
        
        var restaurantList: [RestaurantsAPIResponse]
        restaurantList = fetchedRestaurantList
        
        print("Here is the list \(fetchedRestaurantList)")
    }
}
```

However, when doing this, i no longer get an output when i run my code. What am i doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

For completeness, I have also added a screenshot from Firestore:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3syM.png)

Comment: You are not using `Restaurants` in your code so it's not clear what goes wrong and what you mean with not getting an output. Also how is `Restaurants` declared, please add the code. Off topic but it better to name your model types in singular form so `Restaurant` in this case

Comment: Did you make your ```Restaurants```  struct conform to Codable?

Comment: `let restaurants = document.get("Restaurants")  as? [String: Restaurants]` - this will always be nil as `document.get("Restaurants") is [String: [String: Any]]`. So first you need to get restaurants as array if dictionaries and then map an array to Restaurants struct.

Comment: Also, structure of your firestore database looks somewhat wrong. `Restaurants` should be the array of Restaurant but you used `map`.

Comment: First and foremost, are you completely comfortable with creating a structure using a Firestore document?